# Merge headers of CSV files and fill 0 on missing header

Tags: python, csv, merge, datatable

## Hello

## I would like to merge several CSV files.

I have a reference.csv files with all the headers.

I have several CSV files that can have differents headers.

I want to merge the reference headers to all the other CSV file. In addition, I want to fill with value 0 for all the next rows that's has been added.

There is an example :

reference.csv (My header)

```markdown
a;b;c;d
```

File1.csv

```markdown
a;c 
45;68
```

Expecting result:

File1.csv

```markdown
a;b;c;d
45;0;68;0
```

#I tried this :

(Also tried Pandas, but no working as I want)

```py
import os
import csv

# Get the directory where the Python script is located
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Define the folder containing the CSV files
folder_path = script_directory

# Define the path to the reference text file
reference_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "reference.txt")

# Read the reference columns from the text file
with open(reference_file_path, "r") as reference_file:
    reference_columns = reference_file.read().splitlines()

# Read the header from the file with the most columns
with open(os.path.join(folder_path, reference_file_path ), "r", newline="") as file:
    header_to_copy = next(csv.reader(file, delimiter=";"))

# Iterate through each CSV file and copy the header
for file_name in reference_file_path:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
    data = []

    with open(file_path, "r", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)

    # Update the header in the current file
    original_header = data[0]
    data[0] = header_to_copy

    # Print the differences between the original header and the copied header
    differences = set(original_header) ^ set(header_to_copy)
    print(f"Processed: {file_name}")
    print("Differences:")
    print("+----------------+----------------+")
    print("| Original Header | Copied Header  |")
    print("+----------------+----------------+")

    for item in differences:
        original_present = "Yes" if item in original_header else "No"
        copied_present = "Yes" if item in header_to_copy else "No"
        print(f"| {item:<16}| {original_present:<16}| {copied_present:<16}|")

    print("+----------------+----------------+")

    # Print the position of each element in the header if it was not in the original header
    position_dict = {element: position for position, element in enumerate(header_to_copy, start=1)}
    for element in differences:
        if element in header_to_copy:
            position = position_dict[element]
            print(f"Element '{element}' is at position {position} in the header.")

    # Add a new column with the value "0" from the second row onwards at the specified position
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        for element in differences:
            if element in header_to_copy:
                position = position_dict[element]
                data[i].insert(position - 1, "0")

    # Write the modified data back to the CSV file
    with open(file_path, "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerows(data)
```

*I was thinking to use the position or number of ";" and use it to add a new "0" value. But when there is a specific case it's not working :*

Tried pandas :

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

# Get the directory where the Python script is located
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Define the folder containing the CSV files (same location as the script)
folder_path = script_directory

# Path to the reference.csv file
reference_csv = os.path.join(script_directory, "ref", "reference.csv")

# Read the reference.csv file
reference_df = pd.read_csv(reference_csv)

# List all CSV files in the folder
csv_files = [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith(".csv")]

# Initialize an empty list to store DataFrames
dfs = []

# Iterate through the CSV files in the folder
for csv_file in csv_files:
    # Construct the full path to the current CSV file
    csv_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, csv_file)
    
    # Read the current CSV file
    current_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
    
    # Copy the header row from the reference DataFrame
    reference_header = reference_df.iloc[0].copy()
    
    # Find the positions where the headers differ
    diff_positions = [i for i, (ref_col, cur_col) in enumerate(zip(reference_header, current_df.columns)) if ref_col != cur_col]
    
    # Print the positions if there are differences
    if diff_positions:
        print(f"Differences in headers for {csv_file}:")
        print(diff_positions)
    
    # Concatenate the reference header row with the current DataFrame and fill missing columns with 0
    current_df = pd.concat([reference_header, current_df], ignore_index=True, axis=0).fillna(0)
    
    # Append the merged DataFrame to the list
    dfs.append(current_df)

# Concatenate all DataFrames in the list along columns
result_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)

# Save the merged DataFrame to a new CSV file
result_df.to_csv(os.path.join(script_directory, "merged_data.csv"), index=False)
```

But have this error :

```
  File "parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "parsers.pyx", line 904, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 879, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status
  File "parsers.pyx", line 2058, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 51 fields in line 18153, saw 52
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is the concrete problem you are facing ? SO is made to solve concrete problems, not to provide full solutions to your needs.

Comment: `tried Pandas, but no working as I want` what does that mean? *Pandas* can solve this with a single line by calling eg `concat` to append the data to the empty dataframe

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because I have some UTF-8 codec, When I wasn't using pandas, I didn't have this problem.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with UTF8. This page is UTF8 and all Python 3 strings are Unicode - there's no non-Unicode string in Python 3. If you got an encoding error you probably tried to read a file with non-Unicode characters. Your current code would fail as well What you posted here wouldn't have any problems

Comment: The only problem with the question's code is the trailing whitespace in the header line of the second file. There are no non-ASCII characters in the example, so *all* encodings would work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is the easiest option once we ensure the *column names* are identical. In the second file, the header line has trailing whitespace.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> file1="""a;b;c;d"""
>>> file2="""
... a;c
... 45;68"""
>>>
>>> df_ref=pd.read_csv(StringIO(file1),sep=';')
>>> df_data=pd.read_csv(StringIO(file2),sep=';')
```

The `c` column in the second file contains trailing whitespace.

```
>>> df_data.columns
Index(['a', 'c '], dtype='object')
```

We need to trim this so the columns match

```
>>> # Trim whitespace in the column names
>>> df_data.columns=[c.strip() for c in df_data.columns]
```

After that, a single call to `pd.concat` will combine the two dataframes.

```
>>> df_combined=pd.concat([df_ref,df_data])
>>> df_combined
    a    b   c    d
0  45  NaN  68  NaN
```

Missing values can be replaced with `0` using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) :

```
df_combined=df_combined.fillna(0)
```

We can write the combined data to a file with [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

```
df_combined.to_csv(target_path,sep=';')
```

**Concatenating lots of files**

`pd.concat` works with any sequence of dataframes. We could use `Path.rglob` to load all files in a sequence and concatenate them.

```
from pathlib import Path
root=Path('/path/to/folder')

df_all=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv_path,sep=';') for csv_path in root.rglob("*.csv")])
```

To clean up the data, we can use a separate function :

```
def load_with_trim(csv_path) :
    df=pd.read_csv(csv_path,sep=';')
    df.columns=[c.strip() for c in df.columns]
    return df


all_files=[load_with_trim(csv_path) for csv_path in root.rglob("*.csv")]
df_all=pd.concat(all_files)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,
unfortunately, I have lot of file, I cant fill it by hand. It need to be automated. 
I have also some special character like ü ö é etc

I didn't find the solution to avoid this problem. I'm open to any suggestion

Comment: If you want to load a file containing non-Unicode characters (ie anything above the US-ASCII range) use `encoding='...'` to specify the correct encoding, eg `encoding='latin-1'`.

Comment: @Marius `special character like ü ö é` you just proved there's nothing special about those characters. `read_csv` uses UTF8 by default which means your file is *NOT* UTF8. I'd bet it's `latin-1`. As for `I have lot of file,` so do I, a few hundred in nested folders. You can use `rglob` to find all files, `read_csv` inside a generator to parse them and `pd.concat` to concatenate the entire list

Comment: @Marius I added an example that shows how to use `Path.rglob` to find all files, load and concatenate them

Answer (score 0):

**Try below steps.**

```
1) create a directory and put both csv file in same directory 
2) create new python file like test.py and put below code in python file
3) run test.py and output file is df_merged.csv
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
#read reference csv
df_reference=pd.read_csv('reference.csv', sep=';')
# trim space from header columns
df_reference.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)

#read data csv
df_data=pd.read_csv('File1.csv', sep=';')
# trim space from header columns
df_data.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)

# concat both csv data
df_merged = pd.concat([df_reference,df_data])
df_merged['b'] = df_merged['b'].fillna(0)
df_merged['d'] = df_merged['d'].fillna(0)
#df_merged.drop(labels=[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
print(df_merged.head())
# write merged data in csv file
df_merged.to_csv('df_merged.csv',index=False, sep=";")
```